# vuedraggable works with :list, not v-model with Vue3 composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vuedraggable

I have this Vue3 component using composition API:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive } from "vue";
import draggable from "vuedraggable"
const myArray = reactive([
    { name : "AAA", id : 1},
    { name : "BBB", id : 2},
    { name : "CCC", id : 3},
    { name : "DDD", id : 4}
])
</script>

<template>
  <draggable
    :list="myArray"
    @end="endDrag"
    item-key="id">
    <template #item="{element}">
        <div>{{element.name}}</div>
    </template>
  </draggable>
</template>
```

This works and in `endDrag` routine I see `myArray` rearranged. But if I change `:list` to `v-model` the list on screen does not change and the dragged element returns to its original place. Not to say that `myArray` is not changed.

Bug or feature? I'm doing anything wrong?
Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: Hey, did you resolve the problem? I have pretty the same issue. When I have `myArray = ref([<objects>])` then v-model works well and everyting sort corectly. But when I set `myArray` as `reactive` it loses reactivity - I mean when I `console.log` the `myArray` then I have initial value of array.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. ref should be for array/objects and ref for simple values

Comment: Well, now it works with `v-model` with a computed variable with get/set accessors.
I'm using `"vuedraggable": "^4.1.0"`

Comment: I don't know why was not working before. Seems that using `ref()` and not `reactive()` solves the problem. Sincerely, now it works and do now want to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same problem. Let me share with you my understanding.

First let's establish a few facts.

As it's widely known `v-model` is basically this:

```
<Component :modelValue="myObject" @update:modelValue="(newObject) => myObject = newObject/>
```

If you use the script setup, the const declared and other declarations become a property of an object.

So this:

```
const myObject = reactive({
   id: 'App',
});
```

Becomes this:

```
export default {
  setup() {
    const myObject = reactive({
      id: 'App',
    });

    return {
      myObject,
    };
  },
}
```

Now let's put this knowledge together. When child component emits the event `update:modelValue` with new object, what Vue does is an assignment to the object returned from setup. In pseudo code: `setupObject.myObject = newObjectFromEvent`

You can prove it by this simple code:

```
<script>
import { isProxy, reactive } from 'vue';
import Test from './Test';

export default {
  components: {
    Test
  },
  setup() {
    const myObject = reactive({
      id: 'App',
    });

    const setupObject = {
      myObject,
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(setupObject.myObject);
      console.log(isProxy(setupObject.myObject));
    }, 5000);

    return setupObject;
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <Test v-model="myObject"/>
</template>


<script setup>
import { defineProps, isRef, watch } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps(['modelValue']);

watch(props.modelValue, () => {
  console.log('Value changed!');
});

</script>
<template>
  <button @click="$emit('update:modelValue', { id: 'Test' })">Click me</button>
</template>
```

What you will observe after clicking the button is that our `console.log` will output: `{id: 'Test'}` and `false`.

Also **the watcher from the Test component wouldn't be triggered**, cause our property is no longer reactive and **our Test component still holds the old value of myObject.**

The exact same thing happens with the draggable v-model. When you drag and drop the item, **the property** (in your case `myArray`) that becomes part of a larger object created upon completing the setup code **is overridden with the non-reactive object emitted from draggable component**, thus you don't see item position changed.

Why it works with ref you might ask? Well, going back to our `@update:modelValue="(newObject) => myObject = newObject` if you use ref, the Proxy doesn't vanish, because the assignment is done to the `myObject.value` property. Thus when you used ref it has started working.

Other way to make it work with `reactive` is to handle the update manually:

```
const handleUpdate = (newObject) => {
    Object.assign(myObject, newObject);
};

<Test :modelValue="myObject" @update:modelValue="handleUpdate"/>
```

This way you wouldn't loose the reactivity, cause you keep the same Proxy and just reassign properties.

The bottom line is you have to be very cautious when using v-model with reactive objects or arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the clear exploration! Note that I don't use anymore reactive() in my projects